# How to fix ' Error: invalid read of size 4'

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn C and am completing different challenges in order to learn faster. The code seems logical to me and should progress. However, I'm getting an invalid read of size four on line 29

I've tried to change the data type that gets parsed through, but it didn't seem to work.

```
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct  s_grid
{
  int x;
  int y;
}              t_grid;

void set_point(t_grid *coord, int i, int j)
{
    coord->x = i;
    coord->y = j;
}

//check loccation of next zero
int    where_is_zero(int **sudoku)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    t_grid coord;

    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    while (x < 9)
    {
        y = 0;
        while (y < 9)
        {
            if (sudoku[x][y] == 0) //Here I'm getting the error. 
            {
                set_point(&coord, x, y);
                return (0);
            }
            x++;
        }
        y++;
    }
    return (1);
}

int    solve_sudoku(int **grid)
{

    int row;
    int col;
    int num;
    t_grid coord;

    if (where_is_zero(grid) == 1)
        return (1);

    row = coord.x;
    col = coord.y;
    //where_is_zero(grid);
    num = 1;
    while (num <= 9)
    {
        if (check_number(grid, row, col, num) == 1)
        {
            grid[row][col] = num;
            if (solve_sudoku(grid) == 1)
                    return (1);
            grid[row][col] = 0;
        }
        num++;
    }
    return (0);
}
void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    ft_putstr(char *str)
{
    while (*str != '\0')
    {
        ft_putchar(*str);
        str++;
    }
}
//my main function
int    main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int board[9][9] ={ { 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 5, 3 },
                           { 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4 },
                           { 0, 0, 8, 2, 0, 3, 0, 6, 9 },
                           { 5, 7, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
                           { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                           { 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 6, 3, 7 },
                           { 9, 4, 0, 1, 0, 8, 5, 0, 0 },
                           { 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0 },
                           { 6, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0 } };

    solve_sudoku(board);
    return (0);
}
```

I removed some code just to highlight where the problem is. It should find the next 0 in the table and set the coordinations to my structure.

Comment: For a start: you have `x++` inside your `while (y < 9)` loop, and `y++` inside your `while (x < 9)` loop. You probably want to swap those. Or, easier and better, use a plain for loop for both.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in how you have the loop set up. See my comments below:

```c
    while (x < 9)
    {
        y = 0;
        while (y < 9)
        {
            if (sudoku[x][y] == 0) //Here I'm getting the error. 
            {
                set_point(&coord, x, y);
                return (0);
            }
            x++; // This increments the x index while you're inside the y loop
        }
        y++; // This increments the y index when you meant to increment the x
    }
```

If you swap both lines, that should work fine and will resolve your out-of-bounds error.

What would also help you write this better is instead of using a `while` loop, use a `for` loop. If you haven't covered that topic yet, it's really straightforward:

```c
    for(int x = 0; x < 9 ; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; ++y)
        {
            if (sudoku[x][y] == 0) //Here you won't get the error anymore! 
            {
                set_point(&coord, x, y);
                return (0);
            }
        }
    }
```

What the `for` loop line means there is this: Start the loop by setting it to `0`, at the end of an iteration, increment it. On the next iteration, check if `x` is still less than `9`. If so, proceed with the next iteration.

Comment: I actually still get the same error message even after fixing the x and y implementations as well as changing it into a for loop. :

Comment: @BesnikKonjuhaj can you post your entire error log?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to mixing types. In `main()` you declare:

```
int board[9][9] = { ....
```

You then pass:

```
solve_sudoku(board);
```

`board` has the type `int (*)[9]` (a *pointer to array of int [9]*). See [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). Your `solve_soduku` expects a parameter of type `int**` (*pointer to pointer to int*).

```
int solve_sudoku(int **grid) { ...
```

The type are *NOT* compatible. (and your compiler should be screaming warnings at you)

`board` is a *pointer to array of int [9]*, while `grid` is a *pointer to pointer to int*. You must make the types compatible. The easiest way is to change `solve_sudoku` to

```
int solve_sudoku(int (*grid)[9]) { ...
```

Otherwise you will need to declare `board` as `int**` and allocate and fill in `main()`.

Comment: Huh. I thought that was weird but I didn't realize those types aren't compatible. For my education, can you please elaborate on that? Because essentially, if you have an `int*`, that can essentially function as a pointer to the first element of an `int` array, right? So I thought the `int**` would make sense for a 2D array.

Comment: @brain56 The problem is that a 2D array is an array of 1D arrays, and when it decays to a pointer, it is a pointer to the first 1D array, not the first element. A double pointer `int**` is simply a pointer to pointer. That is why the types are important and not compatible. In the case of the 2D array, you have a pointer to a 1D array of fixed size (`[9]` in your case). Dereferencing `int**` leaves simple *pointer to int*, not *pointer to int [9]*. Further, the 2D array is guaranteed to be contiguous in memory. The pointers of `int**` can point to unrelated areas in memory.

Comment: Awesome explanation! That makes so much more sense now. Thank you!